# how to check whether a specific checkbox is checked using protractor

Tags: protractor

I want to do e2e testing using protractor. My AngularJS application consists of large number of data with checkboxes out of which some will be checked. I want to test whether my required test data are checked.

I tried using below code:

```
expect(element(by.model("accordoptionGroup[optgroup.id][objopt.id].value")).get(index).isSelected()).toBe(true);
```

But error saying `element(..).get` is not a function

Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.get()` method is available on an [`ElementArrayFinder`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder). You meant to have:

```
expect(element.all(by.model("accordoptionGroup[optgroup.id][objopt.id].value")).get(index).isSelected()).toBe(true);
```